# Return number of rows affected by update query?

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a php query:

 `$result = pg_query("UPDATE schema.table SET column = 'value' WHERE column_two = 'value_two');`

I should be able to return an integer value for the number of affected rows using:
`$int_value = pg_num_rows($result)`

I then make a comparison with `$int_value` however neither a result resource or an integer is being assigned to `$int_value`

When i echo the variables, nothing is returned (I would expect a result Id from the initial query and an integer from `$int_value`)

I have echoed & run the query string alone successfully.

How can I assign the integer number of affected rows from the query to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
int pg_affected_rows ( resource $result )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-affected-rows.php